# Users without sufficient rep retagging posts?

Tags: discussion

I happened to be looking at the [Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer) badge, and I noticed that even though the rep required to retag posts is 500, there are many people with rep lower than 500 who have the badge.  I wondered if maybe this is because they retagged their own posts, but I don't have a retag option on sites where my rep is lower.  Anyone know what causes this?

I don't think it's a question of them losing rep after hitting 500, since one of them is down at 1.

Note: almost asked this on StackExchange instead, since I assume it applies to sites other than just StackOverflow.  Feel free to move if I made the wrong call.

Comment: Ah, of course!  When I had looked for the ability to re-tag my own posts on StackExchange sites where I didn't have the requisite rep, it hadn't occurred to me to do the obvious thing - a full edit rather than re-tagging.  Thanks, David & Kip.  (And now I get to edit this post to remove the possible-bug tag...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a little digging around this and found the following revision history for the single question by a user with only 3 rep, and the organizer badge.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1884705/revisions

It appears from this history that the user did edit the question, but not the tags and that then another user edited tags.

Looks like a legitimate bug?

Comment: does retagging your own post count? the user could have retagged it within 5 minutes of posting, which would keep the edit from showing up in the revision history

Comment: @Kip - Good point, I forgot about that wrinkle.

Comment: @Kip Looking at his activity he didn't receive the Organizer badge until Jan 22, yet the question was asked Dec 10, much longer than 5 minutes. http://stackoverflow.com/users/229229?tab=activity#tab-top

Answer (score 5):

Only 100 rep is required to edit community wiki posts, which would probably explain many of these cases. A user can also retag their own post, does that count toward the tag? If so then even a 1-rep user could get the tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly good question for Meta, as it applies directly to StackOverflow and the rest of the trilogy. Probably even more SO than SE because each individual Exchange site can set their own badges (I believe?)

Maybe they edited their posts with different tags? You might want to take a look at the type of questions they've asked and look at the history.

Also, if they did get to 500 reputation, but decided to delete all of their questions/answers, and then got a rep recalc, they could have very little reputation with still having the badges.

Comment: Currently, StackExchange site cannot be customized very deeply.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 5 minute edit window where you can edit your own post and it won't show up in the revisions. The OP probably edited the tags during this window and got the badge.